# Firestore: How to create Document with Custom ID, but only if it doesn't exist?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

Does anyone know how to create a Firestore Document with a specific, non-autogenerated ID?  I would like the operation to fail if the document already exists, and I would like this to be a single operation (not one involving two reads)

---

Looking for Javascript solutions.  Preferably with the web modular API (v9).  I'm not sure how to find the source code for addDoc, so I don't know how to mimic the addDoc process with my own ID.

---

`setDoc` is not a solution to this problem, unless there is a way to make it fail if the document already exists.  The default behaviour of setDoc is to either merge or replace existing documents, not "fail if exists".

Comment: I don't think that's possible but what about checking if document is there, and if no create it using `setDoc`?

Comment: You have to explicitly check to see if it exists first.  You can do that in a transaction if you need the check-and-set to be atomic.